# YouTube videoID Matching and replacing

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm completely stumped on this one, and my complete lack of skill with regular expressions doesn't help.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
- I have multiple NSStrings that contain the text (and links) from blog posts that I've downloaded from a site online. 
- I'm using a UIWebView with an HTML page I create on the fly so that I can have inline images, videos etc.
- The blog posts contain two types of YouTube link - 
`<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID" height="405" width="720" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>` 
and

```
http://youtu.be/VIDEOID
```

There are two different types of URL because the blog uses Wordpress and Wordpress has automatic detection for YouTube links, meaning embeds aren't required. Also the first type of embed doesn't work because it relies on the browser being able to request either http or https (hence the lack of it in the URL there), that apparently doesn't work in UIWebViews.

Essentially what I want to do is find the VideoID from both types of URL, then take the existing URL out of the NSString and replace it with the correct embed type with the correct VideoID attached. I also need to keep the rest of the string intact. To top it all off, it needs to work through multiple URLs in the same NSString, as there are an unknown number of videos per post.

This is the code I have so far, but I know it's horribly wrong and I'm not achieving what I want:

```
NSString *regexToReplaceRawLinks = @"(https?://)?(www\\.)?(youtu\\.be/|youtube\\.com)?(/|/embed/|/v/|/watch\\?v=|/watch\\?.+&v=)([\\w_-]{11})(&.+)?";



NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexToReplaceRawLinks
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];


NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string
                                                           options:0
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                                                      withTemplate:@"<iframe width=\"320\" height=\"180\" src=\"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/$1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen><\/iframe>"];

NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);

return modifiedString;
```

I would be extremely grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction, particularly with the regex's

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `//` can be the start of your url(as you have shown in your example), you can try this regex:

```
(?:https?:)?//(?:[^.]*\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)(?:/|/embed/|/v/|/watch/?\?(?:.+&)?v=)([\w-]{11})
```

Just escape `\` with `\\` from above if you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works great for the short link but doesn't capture the longer version with the iframe already wrapped. I think I'll need to create two separate regex's to cover both